# Young adult novel in which the protagonist is a young woman and her family turns to stone

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

I'm looking for a fantasy book I read as a kid. The protagonist is a young woman and her family turns to stone. She befriends a griffin that is very well spoken and intelligent. One of the parts I remember the clearest is a chapter where she is trapped in a tree surrounded by these monsters that look like goofy dogs with a playful demeanor but they are evil. They attempt to tell her jokes to make her fall out of the tree. The book was pretty reminiscent of *The Spiderwick Chronicles*, with in depth descriptions and pictures of every creature.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: It would have been 2010ish when I read it. No clue on the cover. Many of the creatures were taken from preexisting books but they were often given new names and traits. I remember brownies being a large part of the book. There were also airplanes I believe?